# Is it possible to detect the languages selected in the Android device?

Tags: android, locale

I need to know in my app which languages are selected in the device, is really easy to detect the main one:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

But what I need is the list of languages, I know that this feature in Android was introduced in Lollipop(I think):

[image: languages]

So in the case of my phone (check the picture) I would like to get a list like: "en","it"

Is that possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android versions >= N, you can get the list of Locales, but you have to provide for lower API levels as well.

This should work, although if you want to find one specific Locale from the list, you could do it right there and avoid the copying into a List.

```
final List<Locale> locales;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    final LocaleList list = getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales();
    locales = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        locales.add(list.get(i));
    }
} else {
    locales = Collections.singletonList(getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
}
```

(you may need to change getResources() to context.getResources(), depending on where you use the code)

Comment: Great! That worked really well for me, is the Android version is Nougat is getting what I want (the whole list of languages selected) otherwise is getting the main language which is fine, good solution! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver localeChangeBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED)) {

            Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            // Notify the locale change where you want.
            onLocaleChanged(currentLocale);

        }

    }
};

     private final IntentFilter localeChangeFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(localeChangeBroadcastReceiver, localeChangeFilter);
```

Use this to get broadcast when local is changed.

Comment: Hi @Keyur thanks, but this will be activated only in the case when the user change something from Locale right? and also I have the same problem as I mentioned before, how can I know the list of languages instead of the main one? Cheers